# Meaning of (something -> do)

Tags: haskell

I encountered following function on the Real World Haskell book:

```
namesMatching pat
  | not (isPattern pat) = do
    exists <- doesNameExist pat
    return (if exists then [pat] else [])
  | otherwise = do
    case splitFileName pat of
      ("", baseName) -> do
          curDir <- getCurrentDirectory
          listMatches curDir baseName
      (dirName, baseName) -> do
          -- do something
          return (concat pathNames)
```

What does the following line mean: `("", baseName) -> do` ? I have seen `->` in function type signature but what does this do in this code.

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords#-.3E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `->` is the part of the case syntax that connects a pattern with an expression in an alternative.

`do { ... }` is just an expression.